Pressure sensitive multi touch device
I need a pressure sensitive and multi touch capable device, be it a touch screen, tablet computer or graphic tablet.
Requirements:

Pressure sensitive
Multi touch
Operate with fingers (no pen or the like needed)
Size: at least 10'', bigger is better.
Operating System: Android or Linux in case of a tablet computer, Linux compatible in case of an external device (most USB devices are).
Low latency

Background: I want to experiment with microtonal scales and use it as a keyboard with adjustable layout. Pressure sensitivity is a substitute for velocity dynamics here.
I would buy a lumatone isomorphic keyboard, if it weren't so crazy expensive.
Edit: I don't have a clear Budget. How much I am willing to spend very much depends on size and subjective attraction. So I appreciate options in all price categories. If it seems to be a really cool thing, I might spend 500$ but probably not more.
